QGIS programatically get selected symbology classes
In QGIS, I can select one or more layers or select one or more symbology classes within a layer.

How can I use python to find which of the symbology classes that are selected?
I have been looking into .QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer, but I cannot see any isSelected() or similiar. In which class is this information found?
(I would love to in the end to make a general script, but my use case at the moment is to be able to pick out the selected symbology classes from a Categorized symbology)

Why is this closed? I really had no idea where to look, and it was obiously clear enough for juto96 to understand and give an answer...

In this code snippet, I find the legendNodes of a layer ('my_layer') and check if the respective item in the ItemSelectionModel is selected:
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('my_layer')[0]
layer_renderer = layer.renderer()
legend_symbols_list = layer_renderer.legendSymbolItems()
rule_keys = [item.ruleKey() for item in legend_symbols_list]
layer_tree_view = iface.layerTreeView()
selection_model = layer_tree_view.selectionModel()
layer_tree_model = layer_tree_view.layerTreeModel()

for key in rule_keys:
    node = layer_tree_model.findLegendNode(layer.id(), key)
    legend_index = layer_tree_view.legendNode2index(node)
    print(selection_model.isSelected(legend_index))

